# javascript get parent nested object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I have an object like this for example:

```
obj = {
    subobj1: {

    },
    subobj2: {
        func1: function(){

        },
        func2: function(){

        }
    },
    subobj3: {
        func3: function(){

        },
        func4: function(){

        }        
    },
}
```

How do I call func1 from within func4 without having to call obj.subobj2.func1() ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't exactly. You have no mean to know in what objects your function exists.

Note that it could be in more than one : you could have written this after your existing code :

```
var obj2 = {some:obj.subobj3};
```

So there can't be a unique link (and there is no accessible link) from a property value to the object holding it.

Now, supposing you'd be satisfied with a link made at object creation, you could use a factory to build your object :

```
obj = (function(){
    var parent = {
        subobj1: {

        },
        subobj2: {
            func1: function(){

            },
            func2: function(){

            }
        },
        subobj3: {
            func3: function(){

            },
            func4: function(){
                parent.subobj2.func1();
            }        
        }
    };
    return parent;
})();
```

Then you can call

```
obj.subobj3.func4();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/DFFWy/)

---

**EDIT**

I see you gave the tag OOP to your question. You should know that the pattern I gave is more frequently used to define modules. OOP in javascript is more often done using `new` and `prototype`, in order to enable instances sharing methods and inheritance. As you probably want modules rather than OOP, you seem to be fine, though.

See [this introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Comment: there is function such as this.parent.func1()?

Comment: You can't just set a variable within an object declaration. This doesnt work

Comment: Ah that makes sense, to call subobj2.func1 from outside the factory would I have to call obj.that.suboj2.func1?

Comment: no : you can call directly `obj.suboj2.func1();`. In fact `parent` ("that" before last edit) is private : you couldn't call it outside the factory if it weren't simply obj.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you can add `.parent` to any sub-object with a recursive init:

```
var obj = {
    init: function() {
        for (var i in this) {
            if (typeof this[i] == 'object') {
                    this[i].init = this.init;
                    this[i].init();
                    this[i].parent = this;
            }
        }
        return this;
    },
    subobj1: {
    },
    subobj2: {
        func1: function(){
            console.log('hey');
        },
        func2: function(){
        }
    },
    subobj3: {
        func3: function(){
        },
        func4: function(){
            this.parent.subobj2.func1();
        }        
    }
}.init();

obj.subobj3.func4();
```

With this solution you can also use `.parent` as many times as your nesting requires, like for instance if you had two levels of nesting:

```
this.parent.parent.subobjX.funcY();
```

http://jsbin.com/yuwiducadoma/1/watch?js,console

Comment: This looks like the cleanest working solution, I use it and like it very much. Plus, nesting `.parent` is extremely useful.

Comment: I receive an error when a property is assigned to null. Fixed replacing `if (typeof this[i] == 'object')` with `if (typeof this[i] == 'object' && this[i] !== null)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly, since there is no way to "go up" the object hierarchy like you can with ".." in a filesystem.

What you can do is have variables pointing to the subobjects or subfunctions directly, so that you don't need to go through the hierarchy to call them. The following is a common pattern for creating Javascript modules:

```
obj = (function(){

    var obj1 = {...}
    var obj2 = {...}

    var func3 = function(){...};
    var func4 = function(){...};

    return {
        subobj1: obj1,
        subobj2: obj2,
        subobj3: {
            func3: func3,
            func4: func4
        }
    }
}());
```

In this example, the inner functions can access `obj1`, `obj2`, `func3` and `func4` directly from their variables. The self-calling function makes so these inner variables are private and hidden from the outside and the return statement allows you to export only the functions that you want to make public.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, with a plain object it is not possible to lookup a parent from a nested child.

However, it is possible if you employ recursive [ES6 Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) as helpers.

I've written a library called [ObservableSlim](https://github.com/ElliotNB/observable-slim) that, among other things, allows you to traverse up from a child object to the parent.

Here's a simple example ([jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hp0h5g8v/)):

```
var test = {"hello":{"foo":{"bar":"world"}}};
var proxy = ObservableSlim.create(test, true, function(changes) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(changes));
});

function traverseUp(childObj) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(childObj.__getParent())); // returns test.hello: {"foo":{"bar":"world"}}
    console.log(childObj.__getParent(2)); // attempts to traverse up two levels, returns undefined because test.hello does not have a parent object
};

traverseUp(proxy.hello.foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't possible. Object properties are obtain by the object through which they are set. JavaScript doesn't implicitly set the root object as global, and therefore you can't alias `obj.subobj2.func1` as `func1` or in any way shorter. If you find yourself calling that function excessively, try setting a variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an asnwer more `ActionScript` like and easily to understand:

```
function MainObject() {
   this.x = 100;
   this.y = 50;
   this.second = new SecondObject(this);
}

function SecondObject(p) {
    this.parent = p;
}

var firstobject = new MainObject();

// Saving a reference to SecondObject.
var secondObject = firstobject.second;

// Because of parent variable, you can access second object parent without needing to have the parent object in a variable.
console.log(secondObject.parent.x);
console.log(secondObject.parent.y);
```

Just remember that an object can't have multiple parents.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible with your implementation of the object. Depends on your needs - the following implementation could be useful:

```
obj = function(){
  var obj = {
    subobj1: {

    },
    subobj2: {
        func1: function(){
          console.log('func1');
        },
        func2: function(){

        }
    },
    subobj3: {
        func3: function(){

        },
        func4: function(){
          this.parentObject.subobj2.func1();
        }        
    }
  }
  obj.subobj3.parentObject = obj;
/*  
  //You can also init parentObject reference of the rest of the nested objects if you need
  obj.subobj1.parentObject = obj;
  obj.subobj2.parentObject = obj;
*/  
  return obj;
}();

obj.subobj3.func4();
```

The idea is that nested objects can't know who is their parent, but the parent can tell its children who is he (but then init. code is needed as you can see in my implementation).

You can test it here: http://jsbin.com/eVOpITom/1/edit