# How to access parent of an object in an object

Tags: javascript

Hi guys let's say I have this:

```
function example()
{
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 32;
   this.example2 = function()
   {

   }
}
```

How would I be able to access example.x/example.y from within example2?

I'm asking because I'm creating my first 'real' html5 game and I'm planning on having 1 big Game object and 'Models' within that object (Player, Enemies, etc). Unless there's a better way to do it...I have done working prototypes but they were all in one files and not really structured.

Comment: You can't. This is often asked. Now let's look for another question to close this one as duplicate.

Comment: Oh well that was fast enough, thanks I guess I'll figure out something else

Comment: This one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534153/javascript-get-parent-nested-object

Comment: How are you calling this code and what's the expected output?

Comment: @dystroy - That's not a duplicate. Because OP is dealing with a function here (not just a nested object), there's the possibility of using a closure to good effect.

Comment: @TedHopp We should probably assume that this is used as a constructor.

Comment: @TedHopp I commented a very very different question. OP rewrote it completely.

Comment: Voted to close as the content of the question no longer resembles the original question or the title.

Comment: OP don't change completely your question after it has been commented. You could have deleted it and asked a new one

Comment: I don't see any edit. Questions don't have edits??

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález the edit was made within the grace period

Comment: Ow I see, for a second I thought they don't have edit log... Thanx :P

Comment: @meagar - Let's see--SO policy is to encourage OP to edit a closed question so it can be improved and reopened. Now you want to close the question because OP improved it before it was closed? Better would be to suggest an improved title (or edit the question to improve the title yourself).

Comment: @TedHopp This question wasn't edited to prevent it being closed; it was edited to be a *different question*, after answers and comments had been posted answering the *old* question.

Comment: @meagar - The answers all seem to be to the current question.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
function example()
{
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 32;
   this.example2 = function()
   {
      console.log(this.x); // 0
   }
}
```

Comment: `var _this` is completely redundant. Just use `this.x` and `this.y` inside `example2`.

Comment: This way he cannot acces the parent if he only have a reference to example2.

Comment: No it's not redundant. My solution worked also if he has only a reference to example2.

Comment: if the object were set up as bigObject.ex=new example(), this code would work just fine...

Answer (score 1):

If you object only plans to have 1 parent, you can do it this way:

```
function example() {
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 32;
   this.example2 = new function() {
       this.parent = undefined;
   }
   this.example2.parent = this;
}

var firstobject = new example();

// Saving a reference to example2.
var example2Object = firstobject.example2;

// Because of parent variable, you can access example2 parent without needing to have the parent object in a variable.
console.log(example2Object.parent.x);
console.log(example2Object.parent.y);
```

There are tons of ways of setting `parent`, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your methods to still reference their original object when used in isolation you need a closure:

```
function example()
{
   this.x = 0;
   this.y = 32;

   this.example2 = proxy(this, function() {
       console.log(this.x);
   });
}

var x = new example(),
fn = x.example2; // isolate method

fn(); // this will still work
```

It's using this helper function to bind the function to an object:

```
// helper function to bind fn to ctx (context)
function proxy(ctx, fn)
{
    return function() {
        return fn.apply(ctx, arguments);
    }
}
```